# Jquery Toggle Select All with Image

Tags: jquery, select, toggle

I've got a select all toggle working when using a checkbox.

But when trying to use an image instead it fails and I don't see why..

I've created a fiddle to show what I mean.
**http://jsfiddle.net/70fo0j6q/**

```
This works
<input type="checkbox" id="ckbCheckAll" />

This doesn't
<img src ='images/all.jpg' id='ckbCheckAll2'>ALL</img>
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Invalid HTML. img tag doesn't work like that. It is a self closing tag <img src="..." id="..."  />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because an image don't have a checked property, you need to store the state somewhere else like in a variable or using `data` api

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ckbCheckAll').click(function () {
        $('input[name=A\\[\\]]').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
    });

    var checked = false;
    $('#ckbCheckAll2').click(function () {
        checked = !checked;
        $('input[name=A\\[\\]]').prop('checked', checked);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="ckbCheckAll" />
<p id="checkBoxes">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" id="Checkbox1" name="A[]" />
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" id="Checkbox2" name="A[]" />
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" id="Checkbox3" name="A[]" />
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" id="Checkbox4" name="A[]" />
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" id="Checkbox5" name="A[]" />
    <br />
</p>
<img src='//placehold.it/24&text=ALL' id='ckbCheckAll2'>ALLALL
```

Comment: Hehe.. Same to you.. I'll delete my *non constructive* comment btw.. :p

Answer (score 1):

The image doesn't have a property checked:

```
$(this).prop('checked')
```

try this:

```
$('#ckbCheckAll2').click(function () {
    $('input[name=A\\[\\]]').prop('checked', !$("#Checkbox1").prop('checked'));
});
```